# How to get product category URL Key?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

How can I get the product category's **URL Key**?

I can get the category name by `$category->getName()` but it does not work if I use this `$category->getURLKey()`,

```
$categories = $_product->getCategoryCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

foreach($categories as $category) {
    $productCategoryName = $category->getName();
    var_dump($category->getURLKey());
}
```

Return `null`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your goal is, but you're not going to be able to get category information from $_product. Feel free to ask questions based upon my code below. But my code below will grab the active categories children and their info.  However, this should be a good enough base for what you're looking to do regardless.

```
<!-- Use this section if you're trying to grab children categories and their info  -->

<?php
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())

?>
<div class="subcategories">
    <p>Select a category to view products:</p>
    <ul class="clearfix">
    <!-- Display Each Subcategory Image and Name  Feel Free to remove the img src section to remove the image -->

    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
        <li class="grid12-3">
            <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>" class="clearfix">
                <?php if($thumbFile = $category->getThumbnail()): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $thumbFile;?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />
                <?php endif;?>
                <span><?php echo $category->getName() ?></span></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- End  -->
```

Any questions feel free to ask! Sorry, I just stole an example from a project so the HTML may not line up for a direct copy.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I did it by doing this `$categories = $_product->getCategoryCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
    ->addUrlRewriteToResult();` and then `echo $category->getUrlKey()` - I get the category URL key :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
// for category URL key
var_dump($category->getUrlPath());

// for category URL 
var_dump($category->getUrl());
}
```